# Scrapy spider not saving to csv

Tags: python, csv, text, scrapy, pipeline

I have a spider which reads a list of urls from a text file and saves the title and body text from each. The crawl works but the data does not get saved to csv. I set up a pipeline to save to csv because the normal -o option did not work for me. I did change the settings.py for piepline. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. 
The code is as follows:

Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PrivacyItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = Field()
    title = Field()
    desc = Field()
```

PrivacySpider.py

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from privacy.items import PrivacyItem

class PrivacySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "privacy"
    f = open("urls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    f.close()

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items =[]
    for url in start_urls:
        item = PrivacyItem()
        item['desc'] = hxs.select('//body//p/text()').extract()
        item['title'] = hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()      
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

Pipelines.py

```
import csv

class CSVWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('CONTENT.csv', 'wb'))

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item['title'][0], item['desc'][0]])
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to loop on `start_urls`, scrapy is doing something like this:

```
for url in spider.start_urls:
    request url and call spider.parse() with its response
```

so your parse function should look something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = PrivacyItem()
    item['desc'] = hxs.select('//body//p/text()').extract()
    item['title'] = hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()      
    return item
```

also try to avoid returning lists as item fields, do something like: `hxs.select('..').extract()[0]`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. This is very helpful. It still doesnt save in csv or json, the files remain blank. The suggestion is helpful though. and I appreciate it! I had misunderstood the looping of start_url.

Comment: This worked! I had a silly indentation error. I really appreciate your response.